# Magento customer collection with confirmed users

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection, confirmation

I want to list all the confirmed users with fistname,lastname ect..

### My query:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('userid','firstname','lastname','profile_image','specialist','latitude','free_consult','longitude','sponsored_list','email'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('confirmation', array('null' => true));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('group_id',Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data::LAWYER);
```

But the result is zero,can you please suggest your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try bellow code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('confirmation');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('confirmation', array('null' => true), 'left');
```